# Возможно ли избавиться от SQL-запроса в цикле?

Tags: php, sql

Вопрос в следующем:
Допустим есть таблица:
**city_name | kladr_id | sdek_id**
city_name и kladr_id заполнены. Из API получаю данные и заполняю массив со связью kladr_id - sdek_id. Отношение один-к-одному. Далее в foreach выполняю UPDATE. Понятно что это медленно и неэффективно. Есть ли какие-то варианты избавиться от запроса в цикле.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81649/discussion-on-question-by-------sql-).

Answer (score 1):

Можно найти разные решения...

К примеру используйте транзакции..

```
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE ...
UPDATE ...
COMMIT;
```

или используйте Балк

```
UPDATE table
SET sdek_id = (CASE kladr_id WHEN 1 THEN 'val1'
                 WHEN 2 THEN 'val2'
                 WHEN 3 THEN 'val3'
         END)
WHERE kladr_id IN(1, 2 ,3);
```